# Como mudar o fundo de um gráfico com 'seaborn' em Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

Tento mudar o fundo do meu gráfico com o módulo 'seaborn', porém, não tenho sucesso. Fiz a instalação do módulo hoje (16/04/2021).

código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

arrayx = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
arrayy = np.sin(arrayx)

dat = {"x":arrayx,"y":arrayy}

sns.lineplot(x="x",y="y",data=dat)

sns.set(style='darkgrid')

plt.show()
```

Também tentei outras funções, como `sns.set_style("darkgrid")` e também não funcionou.

[image: Saída:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve excluir a seguinte linha de código:

```
sns.set(style='darkgrid')
```

Em seguida, você deve adicionar a seguinte linha de código antes da construção do gráfico.

```
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
```

Desta forma o código completo ficará:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.set_style("darkgrid")
arrayx = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
arrayy = np.sin(arrayx)

dat = {"x": arrayx, "y": arrayy}

sns.lineplot(x="x", y="y", data=dat)

plt.show()
```

[image: gráfico]

**Observação:** Existe outros estilos que você pode testar, que são: darkgrid, whitegrid, dark, white, ticks

Comment: Muito obrigado! Realmente, eu só tinha que adicionar antes da geração do gráfico.

Comment: @VictorCoutinho Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, aceite a resposta como favorita e der um +1 resposta. Assim você ajuda os outros a encontrarem a melhor solução.